# What is the source outline for a basic word press plugin?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I'm a fairly skilled PHP developer, and watching a tutorial on how to build a WP plugin, with the intention to get my name out there.  What is the outline for a WP plugin that includes database calls?

I could type it from the video, but I'm thinking it would be easier to just do a copy/paste of the plug in similar to how you build an html page. example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The video I watched was: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAwPa4fP90c

Comment: Can you include a link to the video you are watching?

Comment: Did you ask for the code on the original blog post? 
https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin-video-tutorial-4547

Comment: Yes, I did, see: I could type it from the video, but I'm thinking it would be easier to just do a copy/paste of the plug in.

Comment: I totally understand not wanting to type all that out, but looking at the comments for the YouTube page & blog post, not a single person asked for the code. Good luck, maybe someone else will type it all out for you or... just ask the author.

Comment: There are tens of ways to skin this cat, all of them a google or github search away from copy and paste bliss.

Comment: I'm actually looking to build a plugin that I can zip up, and send to the word press community, not install word press, and use some plugin.

Comment: Do I have the concept of "plugin development" with word press wrong?

Comment: I added a link to the WP Plugin Handbook and Best Practices section in my answer below. It might give you some new information or show you're on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the plugin you want to create really but ultimately you should follow the [WordPress Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) / [Best Practices](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/best-practices/).

You'll want to start with the [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](http://wppb.io) ( [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-plugin-boilerplate/) ) or [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate Generator](http://wppb.me) ( [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-plugin-boilerplate-part-2-developing-a-plugin/) ).

Also, a general search for [wp boilerplate plugin](http://www.google.com/search?&q=wp+boilerplate+plugin) should get you on your way.

As for the database part, you just need the structure to start with then find specific code to interact w/databases.

Comment: I have it built in vanilla PHP, and want to plug it into the basic framework with minor manipulation., not use a pre-built plugin to build my plugin into so I can put it out there for all the CMSes.  You failed, because I'm looking for the wrapping that I can submit it to the wordpress community to use.

Comment: Think you failed to understand what he provided you with. You can keep you vanilla PHP in it's own file but there are certain things that are expected of a well-coded WP plugin, like proper uninstall and resource loading, that those boilerplates provide you.

Comment: @Will, thanks. But what ajaxGuru wants is the actual code from the videos but I don't think anyone has asked the author. So the best answer to this question is transcribing the database code - *yawn*

Comment: I'm looking to modify a plugin i wrote for actual use as a word press plugin.

Comment: @ajaxGuru I understand what you're looking to do. You want to modify some php code you've already written so that it will work as a WP Plugin. Those boilerplates are the path—they're just like the HTML example you listed; meaning they're not "existing plugins", they're basic plugin infrastructure/plumbing. It's more boilerplate than a basic HTML page template because it's more complex.

Comment: @Will from here https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate, where wilI find what to copy, and paste for something with a database call?

Comment: @ajaxGuru Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb